# Any one successfully compiled OAT using Android 4.4 ART with LLVM backend?

Tags: android, llvm

Short story: success with default backend, no luck with LLVM backend. Did anyone successfully compiled OAT using LLVM backend (--compiler-backend=Portable)?

Details:

On Android 4.4, I successfully compiled a DEX file to OAT file using the default "Quick" backend, which is the MIR based. When I tried to use LLVM backend "Portable" to do the same thing, there are two problems:

1. When used in the same way as the Quick backend compiled OAT file, the LLVM backend compiled OAT file make the app segfault.
2. LLVM compiled really slow, comparing with default Quick option. Methods took over 100ms to compile in LLVM, and a small DEX takes 1 min to finish. Default Quick backend only uses 2-3 seconds to finish the whole compiling.

Anybody went through this before?